# Exchange 2007 issue internet receive connector

Tags: email, exchange, smtp

I have issue with yahoo.co.uk

if I send a mail from within the yahoo webconsole the mail arrives in my inbox on the exchange server

If I send mail from Iphone configure to send via mail box configure with yahoo setting mail is dropped.

It is not the phone I can send perfectly fine to other exchange 2007 servers same service pack etc.

if you look at the smtprec log below.

this message sent from the phone you can see stops after 354 Start mail input; end with .

,<,EHLO nm26-vm7.bullet.mail.ir2.yahoo.com,
,>,250-mail.marcocm.com Hello [212.82.97.49],
,>,250-SIZE 10485760,
,>,250-PIPELINING,
,>,250-DSN,
,>,250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES,
,>,250-AUTH,
,>,250-8BITMIME,
,>,250-BINARYMIME,
,>,250 CHUNKING,
,<,MAIL FROM:,
,*,08D13F3CADECA060;2014-06-04T11:26:50.898Z;1,receiving message
,>,250 2.1.0 Sender OK,
,<,RCPT TO:,
,>,250 2.1.5 Recipient OK,
,<,DATA,
,>,354 Start mail input; end with .,
,+,,

This is the message hitting the same server sent from yahoo webmail.

,"220 mail.marcocm.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 4 Jun 2014 12:29:26 +0100",
,<,EHLO nm4-vm6.bullet.mail.ir2.yahoo.com,
,>,250-mail.xxx.com Hello [212.82.96.104],
,>,250-SIZE 10485760,
,>,250-PIPELINING,
,>,250-DSN,
,>,250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES,
,>,250-AUTH,
,>,250-8BITMIME,
,>,250-BINARYMIME,
,>,250 CHUNKING,
,<,MAIL FROM:,
,*,08D13F3CADECA06B;2014-06-04T11:29:26.237Z;1,receiving message
,>,250 2.1.0 Sender OK,
,<,RCPT TO:,
,>,250 2.1.5 Recipient OK,
,<,DATA,
,>,354 Start mail input; end with .,
2,>,250 2.6.0 <1401881469.97182.YahooMailNeo@web133206.mail.ir2.yahoo.com> Queued mail for delivery,
<,QUIT,
,>,221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel,
,-,,Local
,+,,

Any Thoughts how to fix this issue much appreciated.

Comment: Hello for all you exchange experts here was my fix.

Comment: Ok after looking at this for a long time and following lots of dead leads.  

I came to the conclusion the exchange server ok.

Checked firewall  mtu ok 

Then I noticed  ips was dropping smtp traffic, I checked the source ipaddress it was yahoo

Ips  smtp scanning traffic turned on and dropping SMTP Content-Transfer-Encoding overflow attempt
 

Turned off and mail arrived.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after looking at this for a long time and following lots of dead leads.

I came to the conclusion the exchange server ok.

Checked firewall mtu ok

Then I noticed by accident the ips was dropping smtp traffic, I checked the source ipaddress it was yahoo

Ips  smtp scanning traffic turned on and dropping SMTP Content-Transfer-Encoding overflow attempt

Turned off and mail arrived.